# Is it possible to reduce information in iptables log?

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

I noticed that there are data in the iptables log that I don't need, so I was wondering if it's possible to change some configuration so that the log has less information, thus reducing the log's size.

For example, I want to know destination and source, but I don't need the window size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: No, one cannot configure it that way.  Iptables is part of the kernel and only takes a limited number of options.  It's possible only to add additional information to the output, e.g. sequence numbers and message prefixes.  Dropping information is not possible.

One possibility would be to use rsyslog to process the logging output.  There are many tutorials explaining how rsyslog can be configured to redirect iptables messages into their own file.  Using templates and fields, it should be doable to keep only those parts of the log-lines that you are interested in.  That's a little bit of work though. Check [rsyslog configuration](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/) if you decide to go that route.